# Setting keys on rotation order using Python in blender

Tags: python, blenderkit

Objective:

1)Select multiple objects

2)change the rotation axis to "XYZ" and key them.

Below is the code I have tried, but its not working for me .Plz
Let me know where i am going wrong on this.

```
import bpy
order = 'XYZ'
context = bpy.context
rig_object = context.active_object
for pb in rig_object.pose.bones:
    pb.rotation_mode = order
    pb.keyframe_insert(data_path ="rotation_euler",frame = 1 )
```

Comment: In step 1 do you mean objects or bones?  Your for loop is trying to set a keyframe on the rotation of every bone in your rig.  If you meant bones, you need to iterate over `context.selected_pose_bones` rather than `rig_object.pose.bones`.  Also, what does 'not working' mean, specifically?  Are you getting error messages or is nothing happening?

Comment: Bones @Marty Fouts

Answer (score 0):

```
import bpy
order = 'XYZ'

if bpy.context:
    if bpy.context.object:
        if bpy.context.object.type == 'ARMATURE':
            bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='POSE')
            for pb in bpy.context.selected_pose_bones:
                pb.rotation_mode = order
                pb.keyframe_insert(data_path ="rotation_euler",frame = 1 )
        else:
            print("not ARMATURE")
    else:
        print("no context.object")
else:
    print("no context")
```

Comment: For some reason its not working for me Sir....... any alternatives??

Comment: try the new one, for selected bones in active object.